# Confused as to why I'm losing scope of a variable using jquery/jsremoting in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, apex-code

The code looks fine to me which is why I'm confused with the G_SResult variable losing scope. It's declared globally above the ready function but that isn't visible in the screenshot. In the screenshot you will see 4 highlighted alert expressions. The one with the red dot is where it returns undefined. The other alerts return the right value.

Screenshot of the code.----> https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQPeB.png

```
function Savedat(){
          var Surveyz=new Survey();
          Surveyz.Name=j$('#survey_name').val();
          var SResult;
          var QuestionOrder=1;
          var id;
          //alert(G_SResult+'----first');
          //alert(typeof G_SResult === 'undefined');
          Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.SV_CreateSurvey.insertSurvey}'
              ,Surveyz
              ,function(Survey_result, event){
                console.log(Survey_result);
                SResult=Survey_result;

             j$('[name="p_Q"]').each(function(){
                 elId=this.id;
                 var elNum=elId.substring(1);

                 QType=j$('input[name=ctrlSel'+elNum+']:checked').val();
                 Quest=new Question();
                 Quest.Question__c=j$(this).val();
                 Quest.Question_Input_Type__c=QType;

                 SResult=Survey_result;
                 G_SResult=SResult;
                  alert(G_SResult+'---1'); 
                 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.SV_CreateSurvey.insertQuestion}'
                      ,Quest
                      ,function(Question_result, event){
                        console.log(Question_result);

                        var SQLink=new SurveyQL();
                        SQLink.SG_Survey__c=SResult;
                        SQLink.Survey_Question__c=Question_result;
                        SQLink.QOrder__c=(QuestionOrder);
                        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.SV_CreateSurvey.insertSurveyLink}'
                              ,SQLink
                              ,function(SurveyLink_result, event){
                                console.log(SurveyLink_result);
                         });

                        j$('[name="A'+elNum+'"]').each(function(){

                             SA=new SurveyAnswer();
                             SA.Answer__c=j$(this).val();
                             SA.Survey_Question__c=Question_result;

                             Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.SV_CreateSurvey.insertAnswer}'
                              ,SA
                              ,function(Answer_result, event){
                                console.log(Answer_result);

                             });
                        });
                     QuestionOrder++;

                 });
                 alert(G_SResult+'----2'); 
             });

            alert(G_SResult+'----3'); 
         });


    setTimeout(function(){Work();}, 1000);


}
```

In case anyone ever comes across this for whatever reason, the solution was this...
(Both code blocks have been edited as a working example)

```
function Work()
{
    //Semaphore like
    if (typeof G_SResult === 'undefined')//(G_SResult == undefined)
    {
      //run stuff here
        setTimeout(function(){Work();}, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
      alert(G_SResult+'----5');



      //G_SResult = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: plz insert the script itself ;)

Comment: Is your debugger broken? ;)

Comment: No, I'm using chrome's debugging tool. The whole idea behind what I'm trying to do is maintain the id until it's time for a page redirect which it will use to pump in the query string. It pumps in undefined so I don't think it's the debugger.

Comment: Lol, I was just trying to imply to USE your debugger. (Is it broken=> why dont you use it, it should become clear what is going on). You can also use the stacktrace.

Comment: Well as much as I appreciate your solution...it's not the one I'm looking for. I'm 99.99999999999% sure this thing should be working and it something jacked up on the salesforce side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Visualforce.remoting.Manager` method is **Asynchronous.**

Answer (score 0):

The variable exists in another scope. It is declared in the anonymous function

```
function Savedat(){

    // [ Code .. ]

    j$('[name="p+Q]').each(

        function(){

            // [ Code.. ]

            G_SResult = 999;
            // G_SResult didnt exist and is therefore declared locally.
            // It implies "var G_SResult = 999"
        }
    );

    // G_SResult undefined here.. because it is outside the scope where it was defined.
}
```

And doesnt exist in the `Savedat(){}` function

Comment: Not sure what you mean? That's just a prefix for the dynamically generated elements. The only other place it's used is prior to the function being called. It's also inserting everything fine...it's when I try to keep the id being returned after the insert.
http://i.imgur.com/PeBZZ.png

Comment: It exists globally above the ready function though. This is what I'm talking about...


    `var G_SResult;


    j$(function() {`

Comment: I only see `var SResult` not `var G_SResult` outside the `j$()`. If it exists outside Savedat then I'd get it too.

Comment: Right, there is a lot more going on there then I'm showing. What I'm showing is where the problem is though. Are you saying I would still get the error even though G_SResult was declared outside of the savedat function? Am I wrong to think that since it's a global variable, no matter where the data is being set, it should still maintain that data?

Comment: No, if the variable was indeed declared outside the `Savedat`, then the Asynchronous answer is rather likely. But you you haven't been clear about where it was declared, so scope would be the first thing to consider. Scope IS well the main thing if you want to access the variable somewhere.

Comment: It's Asynchronous. I started getting assistance from a colleague and they have also verified that. I'm going to try and see if I can leverage a semaphore or delay for this specific situation.

Comment: Lol ok. I guess you'll want to do "something" when the variable is filled, which can be done using callbacks.. You should mark an answer as useful.